# Opening a mdf file in matlab

Tags: matlab, mat, mdf

I used to use [tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9622-mdf-import-tool-and-function) to convert those mdf files to .mat, but apparenlty the developer hasn't updated it. It does not work any more.

Is there any other tool with which i can convert to .mat file or directly load and open the .mdf file?

error:

```js
     
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in mdfimport>Load_MDF_File_Callback (line 603)
cd (handles.pathName); % Change to current or last
directory looked at

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in mdfimport (line 87)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
 
Error while evaluating uimenu Callback
```

Comment: thought about fixing it? "does not work anymore" is a bad problem description anyway... The mdf-files I assume you're talking about are usually generated by a certain piece of hardware, aren't they? So why not contact the manufacturer of the hardware for his solution?

Comment: It's very high level coding for my understanding to fix it. Plus it's not my code. I have pasted the error if you could give it a shot.

Comment: The error description seems simple to me. But we're not a debugging service. But maybe it was already fixed by somebody else in the FEX comment section?

Answer (score 0):

For reference: if you have MATLAB R2016b or later, and your MATLAB licence includes the [Powertrain Blockset](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/autoblks/index.html) or the [Vehicle Network Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/vehicle-network.html), you can use the [`mdf` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vnt/ug/mdf.html) to read MDF files.